# Date formatting issue in LDS lightning-record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lds

We have built LDS forms using lightning-record-edit-form, lightning-input-field tag is used for date which displays standard locale date format as per documentation. The problem is, it is always displaying date in medium format of locale i.e. Jul 1, 2021 not in short format 06/01/2021. Any pointers to display date in mm/dd/yyyy format using lightning-input-field? Is this a salesforce limitation?

We cannot change the tag to lightning-input field and add apex since such change will defeat the purpose of using LDS and will result in revamp of all 20+ forms just for 1 date format issue.

Comment: I believe this is something with setting of your user. For me with CZ locale i have displayed the date as 28.2.2022, if i login as someon with EN locale i have it like 2/28/2022.

Comment: User is using en_US locale, only in LDS form with lightning-input-field is showing date in medium format instead of short format otherwise in lightning experience it is mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
handlesubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();  
   console.log('handle submit');

   const fields = event.detail.fields;
   fields.Travel_Dates_Sent_to_PS__c = false;

   if (this.updatetype=="cancel"){
      let todaydate = this.formatDate();
      fields.Travel_End_Date__c=todaydate;
   }
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}

formatDate() {
   console.log('formatDate');
   let d = new Date();
   let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
   let day = '' + d.getDate();
   let year = d.getFullYear();
   if (month.length < 2) 
       month = '0' + month;
   if (day.length < 2) 
       day = '0' + day;
   return [day, month ,year,  ].join('/');
}
```

Please refer this   [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IR1FQAW/) for more details

Comment: Links can stop working so it'd be great if you can add some of those relevant details to your answer with an [edit]